# How to edit a file while copying from another

Tags: c, linux

How I can edit a file while copying its content from another

```
source = fopen("sourceFile.txt", "r");
          if( source == NULL ) 
            {
                printf("Error in doStepOneAndTwo, can't open file source \n");
                return USERERR;
            }

target = fopen("targetFile.txt", "w");
          if( target == NULL ) 
            {
                fclose(source);
                printf("Error in doStepOneAndTwo, can't open file target %s \n",str);
                return USERERR;
            }

while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF ) 
          {
              fputc(ch, target);
              //Here I need to check if ch == "blah" change it to "twoBlah" and save twoBlah to targetFile.txt instead of blah
          }
```

I have problem with the syntax

Comment: Please add the exact error you get.

Comment: You edit first, then copy it. Or, make a copy, edit that copy. Easy as that.

Comment: Use `fgets` to get a line at a time from the file, use `strtok` to break up the line into individual words, use `strncmp` to compare the word with your desired string and finally use `write` to write the original word or the changed word. That's the summary.

Comment: `ch` is only a single character (I hope you specified `int ch`). Let `sed` do the job, or check the `sed` source how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *search_word = "blah";
const char *replace_word = "twoBlah";
const char *p = search_word;

while(1){
    ch = fgetc(source);
    if(*p == ch){
        ++p;
        if(!*p){//match!
            fprintf(target, "%s", replace_word);
            p = search_word;
        }
    } else {
        if(p != search_word){
            const char *temp = search_word;
            while(temp != p)
                fputc(*temp++, target);
            p = search_word;
        }
        if(ch == EOF)
            break;
        fputc(ch, target);
    }
}
```